# Free cartographic texture resources

Tags: polygon, cartography, tilemill, image, filling

I've been trying without success to find free textures to use in TileMill. I'm looking for fairly simple, abstract textures, like a dotted pattern (to indicate national parks). Are there any well known resources for this kind of thing?

Comment: National Parks needs to be a line (dotted line) and polygon (fill colour) you need to used CartoCSS to style your data reference is here http://www.mapbox.com/carto/api/2.1.0/#line-dasharray example: http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/carto/

Comment: I'm pretty comfortable with Carto and TileMill. I want to use a very light texture as I'm overlaying over hill shaded terrain.